# How do I loop horizontal gallery using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a horizontal gallery that will display mixtape covers, I have five divs with an id of panel_1, panel_2, etc. What happends is when I reach panel 5 and continue to scroll, it doesnt loop back to panel 1 again as I would like it to.

You can view what I have so far here: http://worldwidemixtapes.com/newtheme.html

My knowledge of jQuery is beginner but I have implemented jquery plugins before and can understand some of the methods if explained well.

This is my first question so if its too vague, please let me know so I can be more specific.

Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="mixtapeWallInner">
<div id="panel_1" class="mixtapePanel current" style="left: -972px; "></div>
<div id="panel_2" class="mixtapePanel" style="left: -972px; "></div>
<div id="panel_3" class="mixtapePanel" style="left: -972px; "></div>
<div id="panel_4" class="mixtapePanel" style="left: -972px; "></div>
<div id="panel_5" class="mixtapePanel last" style="left: -972px; "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 2:

Took a little time but I coded up a "seemingly endless" carousel. Pretty much what happens here is the script will move a `div` in the DOM to the end or beginning of the cycle depending on which direction you're moving.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/8GKz6/11

(Please include the comments when using this code.)

---

Solution 1:

When creating a content "carousel" such as this a common technique is to jump back to the first DIV when you're trying to scroll past the last DIV. Here is a basic example I coded up...

http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/VFwLT/5/

Comment: I see where you're going with this and this is fine. But I'm trying to achieve something like the carousel shown on http://lifeandtimes.com. On there, it gets to the last div panel and just cycles through again.

Comment: @dporchia Check out my new solution. That should do the trick. Let me know if you find any bugs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this out tonight and let you know how this works out.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is keep at least one panel off the screen and have a copy of it ready to move into place either from the left or the right. I will be writing a blog later this week on how to replicate the Windows Phone Panel control in HTML5, which does this. You can check out my sample site http://m.movie.extremewebworks.com.
So as you move between panels you move the off screen panels to either the right or the left to keep things flowing smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris but I dont fully understand what you mean. I have panel_4 and panel_5 off the screen to the right and panel_1 and panel_2 off screen to the left. From what you're saying is that I need to create another one of those panels? what would be the jQuery method used to keep the loop of 5 panels going?