# jQuery horizontal slider loop to the first item

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, reverse

I'm developing a jQuery horizontal slider and I want to know if it is possible when I am at the last item instead of having this reverse effect that it loops to the first item ?
Do you know what should I modify in my jQuery script ?

[HERE MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jarod51/2jfvY/)

```
$(function () {
    var 
        animation = function ( href ) {
            var 
                name = "active",
                element = $( "a[href='" + href + "']" );

            $( "html, body" ).stop().animate( {
                scrollLeft: $( href ).offset().left
            }, 1200 );

            element.closest( "ul" ).find( "li" ).removeClass( name );
            element.parent().addClass( name );
        },
        menu = $( "#list" );

    animation( menu.find( "li" ).eq( 0 ).find( "> a" ).attr( "href" ) );

    $( "#cssmenu a" ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
        var target = $( this ).attr("href");

        animation( target );

        event.preventDefault();
    } );

    $( "#next, #prev" ).click( function ( event ) {
        var
            positionActiveClass = menu.find( "> li.active" ).index(),
            menuLength = menu.find( "> li" ).length - 1,
            buttonId = $( this ).attr( "id" );

        if ( buttonId === "next" ) {
            if ( positionActiveClass === ( menuLength ) ) {
                newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( 0 );
                newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                animation( newPositionActiveClass );
            } else {
                newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass + 1 );
                newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                animation( newPositionActiveClass );
            }
        } else {
            if ( positionActiveClass === 0 ) {
                newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( menuLength );
                newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                animation( newPositionActiveClass );
            } else {
                newElementActiveClass = menu.find( "li" ).eq( positionActiveClass - 1 );
                newPositionActiveClass = newElementActiveClass.find( "> a" ).attr( "href" );

                animation( newPositionActiveClass );
            }
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    } );

} );
```

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170709/how-do-i-loop-horizontal-gallery-using-jquery) you can do the same thing using your li items.

Comment: Hi Pow-lan, I took a look at this link, thanks. The problem, there is also a reverse effect when they are the last item. I don't want this reverse effect when I'm in the last item

Comment: which is what the question I referenced does. They modify the DOM on each click instead of just moving the visible window around. Without modifying the DOM you are not going to be able to create a 'loop' because you will always have to scroll to the left to get to the first item. The only way you could do this is to move the items around on each click so that instead of scrolling the window you are bringing things into and out of view in the DOM itself.

Comment: may be I didn't express well myself

Comment: I think you have, here is my u nderstanding: Right now as you click the links it moves left or right to the next item. If you are at the end, you don't want it to scroll all the way back to the first item, you want it to be able to 'wrap around' to the first item. Right?

Comment: yes exactly Pow-lan :-).

Comment: And you will only be able to do that by mutating the DOM.